# SQL server 2019 на windows 11 не устанавливается

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-11

Всем привет пытаюсь установить ms sql server exp 2019 на windows 11 и постоянно вылетает ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же ошибку выдает и в службах
ошибка 1067
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот еще из папки с сервером
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытался устанавливать и developer версию результат тот же
вот что выдает студия при подключении
error 26
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Журнал ошибок Windows смотрите

Comment: в журнале ошибок нашел список всех ошибок подскажите пожалуйста как их исправить

Comment: Имя сбойного приложения: sqlservr.exe, версия: 2019.150.2000.5, метка времени: 0x5d8a9215
Имя сбойного модуля: ntdll.dll, версия: 10.0.22000.708, метка времени: 0xb998b765
Код исключения: 0xc0000005
Смещение ошибки: 0x0000000000035c7e
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x99c
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d8727515692c10
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Идентификатор отчета: 29f3c485-32fa-4189-9c90-0351b6d50f13

Comment: Решение нашел тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size#resolutions